# How to install GDB in windows when building shogun from source?

Tags: shogun

I tried compiling shogun from source in windows but after writing

cmake [options] ..

command i get this error:

-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.0 to target Windows 10.0.15063.
-- Could NOT find GDB (missing: GDB_COMMAND GDB_VERSION)
CMake Error at src/shogun/CMakeLists.txt:57 (MESSAGE):
  Shogun can only be built with GPL codes if the source files are in
  C:/Users/user/Desktop/shogun/src/gpl.  Please download or disable with
  LICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF.

I tried installing GDB from MinGW but it didn't worked

how to proceed further ?

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the first results when googling for the error so I'll post an answer here and link to relevant websites.

Shogun uses submodules to separate the main [BSD](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/blob/e509f8c57f47dc74b3f791d450a70b770d11582a/LICENSE) (Berkeley Software Distribution) licensed library from the [GPL](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun-gpl/blob/43213cfdd88734ba2fa52f53d7f4a347c784b6c0/LICENSE.md) (GNU General Public Licence) licensed files (for the difference between those see an example article [here](https://fosswire.com/post/2007/04/the-differences-between-the-gpl-lgpl-and-the-bsd/)). After cloning the repository you'll need to invoke `git submodule update --init` comand as specified in [the documentation](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/blob/e509f8c57f47dc74b3f791d450a70b770d11582a/doc/readme/INSTALL.md#basics-) which will pull `shogun-gpl` repository (among others) into `shogun-gpl` directory. See also [this](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/issues/4086) GitHub issue.